# In Marklogic (5.x), how can I include a doctype declaration in a zipped document?

Tags: zip, doctype, output, marklogic

I have a document that I run through an `xslt` and then capture in a variable, e.g. $doc.

The `xslt` has the requisite output options set so that I can get my `docytpe` declaration prolog in the document, and when I do an `xdmp:save` with $doc, reiterating the output settings in the save options node (but is that necessary?), I happily get my `doctype` declaration, as specified in my `<xsl:output/>` options.

However, I would like to zip up the document that I get together with other, binary documents, and save that.

But the the zipped up document, does not contain my `doctype` declaration.

I create the zip via a function in a module that has the requisitie xdmp:output options set as for the `xslt`, but `MarkLogic/Xquery-style`. And my zip function is like so:

```
`declare function p2n:bundle-document($basename as xs:string, $doc as document-node()) as binary()
{
  let $manifest := <parts xmlns="xdmp:zip">
                    {
                      <part>{$basename}</part>
                    }
                   </parts>
 let $zip       := xdmp:zip-create($manifest, $doc)
 return $zip  
};`
```

To no avail, alas. When I finally open up the zip, and there is no `DOCTYPE` declaration.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply xdmp:quote, and wrap the result in a text node to do this, for example like this:

```
let $basename := "test.xml"
let $xsl :=
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:output doctype-public="test" doctype-system="test"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>

let $xml := <test/>
let $doc := text { xdmp:quote(xdmp:xslt-eval($xsl, $xml))}
let $manifest :=
    <parts xmlns="xdmp:zip">{
        <part>{$basename}</part>
    }</parts>
let $zip := xdmp:zip-create($manifest, $doc)
return
    xdmp:save("d:\tmp\test.zip", $zip)
```

HTH!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much, @grtjn! I do not quite understand why it should, however. The xdmp:quote escapes the **<** and **>** into **&lt;** and **&gt;**, yes? The **text{}** just wraps it into a text node -- or does it resolve the entities too, at that point? Why?

Comment: @FondDuLac You need to force the processor to serialize the XSLT result without further processing inside XQuery, as that would negate the output options from the XSLT. xdmp:quote does that, and effectively converts it to a string containing < and >. Wrapping this inside a text node is required by xdmp:zip-create, but it also ensures it is written as text, without any character escaping. But if you would embed the serialized XML inside $doc in other XML, that would force converting < into &lt; at serialization..